Remeber me on the wagtail admin login interface cannot be clicked
Remeber me on the wagtail admin login interface cannot be clicked.
I just ran the demo of wagtail and found that the 'remember me' option on the admin login interface cannot be selected. All other input boxes are functioning normally. I use wagtail5.3 and Django 5.1.3.
I just used these basic installation items.

pip install wagtail
wagtail start mysite mysite
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
Replace the database from SQLite to MySQL
python manage.py runserver

Is this a bug, or did I miss a step during setup?
enter image description here
The login function is normal. The other buttons on the backend interface are also normal.Only the checkbox cannot be selected.I have tested it on both Edge、Chrome and firefox.
